# What is this kind of recursion?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Consider the following expression:

For any fixed integer $a$, for real $x_i$

Pick an $x_0$ such that

$ln(ln(a))/ln(ln(a*100*x_0))=x_1$

Then substitute $x_0\mapsto x_1$

$ln(ln(a))/ln(ln(a*100*x_1))=x_2$

This recursive substitution rapidly converges to

$ln(ln(a))/ln(ln(a*100*x_f))=x_f$

Surprisingly, the x on the LHS = the x on the RHS in the limit, but I don't understand how or why this works.

For example, try $a=12345$ and $x_0=.5$

In nine steps, the limit of my calculator precision, gives

$x_f= .85298413171479$ for the first $14$ places.

Can someone explain?

Comment: What's to explain? You may iterate literally ***any*** function. Some converge, some don't. This one did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just trying to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=x \log (\log (100 a x))-\log (\log (a))$$ It would be faster to use Newton method
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ where
$$f'(x)=\log (\log (100 a x))+\frac{1}{\log (100 a x)}$$ For your example
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.500000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.855621847158219 \\
 2 & 0.852984232495788 \\
 3 & 0.852984131714761 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you let $a=10^k$, a very first estimate is
$$x_0=\frac{1+(k+2) \log (10) \log (k \log (10))}{1+(k+2) \log (10) \log   ((k+2) \log (10))}$$
$$k=\frac{\log (12345)}{\log (10)}\quad \implies \quad x_0=0.853263$$ By Darboux theorem, we know that $x_0$ is an over estimate of the solution.